# TeamViewer does not start automatically, how do I make sure it does?

Tags: services, teamviewer

After installing TeamViewer x86 on Ubuntu, it will not start automatically on boot, even when telling it to do so via the application settings ("Start TeamViewer with system"). How do I make sure TeamViewer starts with the system, before even logging in?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

TeamViewer provides a script called `teamviewerd.sysv` available in `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script`. Here's an excerpt:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# /etc/init.d/teamviewerd
#
# chkconfig: 2345 95 05
# description: daemon for TeamViewer
#
# processname: teamviewerd
# config: /etc/teamviewer/global.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/teamviewerd.pid

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          teamviewerd
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named
# Short-Description: TeamViewer remote control daemon
# Description:       TeamViewer remote control daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

All you need to do is make sure this script runs on startup. Making sure of this is relatively simple, just copy it to `/etc/init.d` like so:

```
cd /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script
sudo cp teamviewerd.sysv /etc/init.d/
```

Don't forget to make the script non-writable to anyone but the owner!

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/teamviewerd.sysv
```

Then run

```
sudo update-rc.d teamviewerd.sysv defaults
```

The service will now start automatically with each boot. If you don't feel like rebooting, you can start the service manually with:

```
sudo service teamviewerd.sysv start
```

**2019 EDIT**: This answer was written in 2013. Since then, `systemd` has arrived in force and is normally used for constructing services that start upon boot. For instructions on how to achieve this in `systemd` instead, please see this question: [How do I run a single command at startup using systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd)

Comment: regarding the 2019 edit: will the old way still work,  because it is a lot simpler

Comment: You should do it in systemd.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Teamviewer version 9 and there is option `Start TeamViewer with system`. By enabling this option, teamviewer register as a system service and automatically start with the system. Reboot system and it starts with the system **before logging in**.

[image]

In Teamviewer 11, it can be enabled from the main desk.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that running `teamviewer` renders the same result as running the daemon?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach that works for me:

1. Enable Teamviewer at start up

Go to `Extras -> Options -> General -> Check Start TeamViewer with system`

2. Enable Teamviewer before login

   `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Uncomment this line:

`WaylandEnable=false`

Answer (score -1):

Create a soft-line of `teamviewer` in your run level file location. You can do that by using:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/teamviewer /etc/init.d/
```

or if your system is using `systemctl` then use:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/teamviewer /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is:

In TeamViewer, go to Extras > Options > General > check the box next to "Start TeamViewer with system"/

You will need to assign the computer to your account otherwise passwords can change anytime.