# Teamviewer goes offline after 10 seconds

Tags: teamviewer

Teamviewer goes off-line after 10 seconds
I installed Teamviewer in Ubuntu. 
The settings [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427125/teamviewer-does-not-start-automatically-how-do-i-make-sure-it-does#new-answer?newreg=bc382a14f61b4a9a854e6f9716b77a54) I did.
When I auto login in Ubuntu I show-up on-line for a while but after 10 seconds I am off-line again in windows. When I select Teamviewer in Ubuntu I am on-line at once and stay in this way. I checked all the settings of Teamviewer, they are all the same as in my Window computer.

Comment: Do you have a corporate edition of teamviewer?

Comment: Reading back my question was not very clear, this is what I meant:After the Ubuntu server is start-up I can see its on-line on my Windows Teamviewer.
But after 10 seconds the Ubuntu user goes off-line again.

When , after this, I directly go to the GIU of the Ubuntu server 
and only select Teamviewer I become on-line at once and stay in this way. 
I checked all the settings of Teamviewer, they are all the same as in my Window computer. I have a free version Teamviewer