# How do I run a single command at startup using systemd?

Tags: startup, systemd

I'd like to startup an Apache Spark cluster after boot using the following command:

```
sudo ./path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Then run this command when the system prepares to reboot/shutdown:

```
sudo ./path/to/spark/sbin/stop-all.sh
```

How can I get started? Is there a basic template I can build on?

I've tried to use an extremely simple (file: `/lib/systemd/system/spark.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Spark service

[Service]
ExecStart=sudo ./path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Which doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: Hi @WillemK, I had looked at this page already. This issue I found is I can't just replace `exec` with `ExecStart=`.  Plus, I haven't used upstart before.

Comment: The dot before the path of your script looks extremely suspicious.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I think OP is trying to run the script the way OP would in the terminal hence the `.`...

Comment: Hi @AndreaLazzarotto, this is correct. Apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: @George yes I think so too, however using relative paths in services could lead to errors due to the different PATH. I suggest to use absolute paths instead.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, I've been trying to use an absolute path but as you can see in my response to the answer given I'm getting an absolute path error.  The .sh is located at `/usr/lib/spark-2.1/sbin/start-all.sh` and this is what I've supplied.  Is this not the absolute path?

Comment: @macourtney7 see my updated and the link to a working tutorial with more comprehensive options for systemd

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Your `.service` file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Spark service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, take a few more steps to enable and use the `.service` file:

1. Place it in `/etc/systemd/system` folder with a name like `myfirst.service`.
2. Make sure that your script is executable with:

   ```
    chmod u+x /path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh
   ```
3. Start it:

   ```
    sudo systemctl start myfirst
   ```
4. Enable it to run at boot:

   ```
    sudo systemctl enable myfirst
   ```
5. Stop it:

   ```
    sudo systemctl stop myfirst
   ```

#### Notes

1. You don't need to launch Spark with `sudo` in your service, as the default service user is already root.
2. Look at the links below for more `systemd` options.

#### Moreover

Now what we have above is just rudimentary, here is a complete setup for spark:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Spark Master and Slave Servers
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target
 
[Service]
User=spark
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh
ExecStop=/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/stop-all.sh
TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To setup the service:

```
sudo systemctl start spark.service
sudo systemctl stop spark.service
sudo systemctl enable spark.service
```

#### Further reading

Please read through the following links. Spark is a complex setup, so you should understand how it integrates with Ubuntu's init service.

- https://datasciencenovice.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/spark-stand-alone-cluster-as-a-systemd-service-ubuntu-16-04centos-7/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I've created a file based on what you suggested. Upon running `sudo systemctl start spark` is receive the following error: `Failed to start spark.service: Unit spark.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status spark.service' for details.`

Comment: The main part of `systemctl status spark.service` is as follows: `Executable path is not absolute` and `spark.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.`

Comment: The issues are 1) Spark binary path (should replace what we have in the service file) is needed, 2) Spark has a shut down command what is it. 3) Did you go through the links I gave you. I don't use spark so supply them

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks for your answer, my question is how can I run spark under a specific command after rebooting?The question is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/979498/how-to-start-a-zookeeper-daemon-after-booting-under-specific-user-in-ubuntu-serv

Comment: Please advise that user and administration units should now be put in `/etc/systemd/system` and not in `/lib/systemd/system`. `systemclt enable myservice` will not work in `/lib/systemd`. @see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd-system

Answer (score 6):

Copy-paste this into a terminal (as root) to create `/root/boot.sh` and run it on boot:

```
bootscript=/root/boot.sh
servicename=customboot

cat > $bootscript <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$bootscript ran at \$(date)!" > /tmp/it-works
EOF

chmod +x $bootscript

cat > /etc/systemd/system/$servicename.service <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=$bootscript
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF

systemctl enable $servicename
```

To modify the parameters, for example to use a different `$bootscript`, just set that variable manually and skip that line when copying the commands.

After running the commands, you can edit `/root/boot.sh` using your favorite editor, and it will run on next boot. You can also immediately run it by using:

```
systemctl start $servicename
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by systemd docs, but shouldn't it be
`Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes` or systemd will consider the task inactive unless the custom script leaves some processes running.

Comment: @PeterLamberg I tried reading systemd docs too and yet here we both are ;). I remember they weren't very clear, but the answer I posted works for me on multiple systems (I revisit this page every now and then when I need it again). Do you mean that, because it's considered 'inactive', every successive 'start' call will re-run the script? Because I would consider that as expected for a shell script. I'd find it weird if I had to 'stop' something that isn't actually running before I can start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Adding startup items in systemd is complex and cumbersome. To make this more convenient, I have wirte a tool [add_service](https://github.com/DIYer22/add_service) which provides a simple way to quickly add startup item in systemd.

Install:

```
pip3 install add_service
```

Usage:

```
python -m add_service [shell_file/cmd] [user (default `whoami`)]
```

Examples:

```bsh
python -m add_service ssh_nat.sh  # by default user is `whoami`
python -m add_service "`which python3` -m http.server 80" root
```

Comment: Is this your script? If so, please disclose that in the answer, both here and in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687324/70524