# Start Specific Terminal on Startup

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, systemd, autostart

I coded an application using libpcap and ncurses. Obviously, this application is supposed to run in the terminal.

Therefore, I created a script that launches my application in gnome-terminal with a fixed size:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --geometry=75x36+0+0 --command="myapplication"'
```

I want to execute that on startup (after the desktop of the current logged in user has shown up). It is important to run this as root. Otherwise, libpcap won't be able to sniff for packets. I am aware of all the risks involved.

I created the following `.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Application

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myshellfile

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I put it in `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` and preset it with

```
sudo systemctl preset myservice.service
```

Nevertheless, it does not work. What am I doing wrong here? Running Ubuntu 16.04 in an updated state.

Comment: Should the terminal remain open? You may use Startup applications. I have an idea how that could be done.

Comment: @pa4080 Exactly! My application has a CLI, so it needs to stay open. Its blocking btw - so as soon as you run the application, it stays open and doesn't close itself :)

Comment: Hi, TacoVox, sorry for the late answer, but I had not enough free time previous days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible methods to launch GUI application (as *gmome-terminal*) at system startup and maybe the most appropriate is to use [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) (see [also](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html)). In this way the app will be started when the user login. (In every other method we should export some desktop envvars to be able to do that.)

---

To be able to test my answer, I created executable file, called `myapp`, located in `/usr/local/bin`. It adds just the current date and time within a file in the `/root` directory, so we will need root (sudo) permissions to run the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
date >> /root/date.txt
```

---

We can grant permissions to a specific user to run a command without password via `sudo`. No matter whether the user belongs to the *sudoers* group or not. We can use **`sudo visudo`** to edit safely `/etc/sudoers` and add one or more lines as these:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myapp
user2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myapp
```

The better idea is to create a separate file, for example `/etc/sudoers.d/myapp`, where to put these rules. For this purpose we shall use the command: **`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myapp`**.

Now `user1` and `user2` should be able to run `sudo myapp` without password.

> **Note:** Always use the command [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) to edit the `sudoers` file to make sure you do not lock yourself out of the system – just in
>   case you accidentally write something incorrect to the `sudoers` file.
>   `visudo` will save your modified file to a temporary location and will
>   *only* overwrite the real `sudoers` file if the modified file can be parsed without errors... [**source**](https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/566421).

---

The next step is to modify the startup script. Let's call it `myapp_startup` and place it into the same directory `/usr/local/bin`. The script content should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --geometry=75x36+0+0 -x bash -c "sudo myapp; exec bash"
```

- Detailed explanation about the above command is provided [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/967720/566421).
- If you want to minimise the window automatically use: [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/a/962068/566421) approach.

---

Now we can create an entry in [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) as this:

[image]

- Additionally we can modify the startup script in this way: `sleep 3 && gnome-terminal ...` to launch the new terminal window after the entire desktop is initialised.
- When the script isn't located within a directory that is added to user's `$PATH` variable (`echo $PATH`) we should use the full path, for example: `/usr/local/bin/myapp_startup`.

---

Further reading:

- Instead of *gnome-terminal* probably you can use `tmux` ([or some other session manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921494/keep-running-a-python-program-even-after-logging-off-the-ssh-session)) as it is described [**in this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/962820/566421).
- Additionally you can launch the startup script via Cron (or some other limited environment) by the script `cron-gui-launcher.bash` from this project: https://github.com/pa4080/cron-gui-launcher. This script will wait the user to login and then will export all DE Variables, etc... But in the current case the final result will be the same as we using Startup Application.