# how can I open a extra console and run a program in it with one command?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, xterm

So I know if I type gnome-terminal or xterm, a new window will be popped out. Then I checked the man page for these two, nothing relevant found.

Then I noticed under Mac you can do it with the program open. But it seems under Linux it's not that trivial.

Does anyone have experience?

Comment: See `man gnome-terminal` again. It's there.

Comment: To get only what are interested from `man` command or `some-command --help` flag, use `grep` in pipe. I'd try `man gnome-terminal | grep run` or `man gnome-terminal | grep command` what will filter the output.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update:** The new recommended syntax is:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "<my command or script>; exec bash"
```

- If you want to reach the users home directory within the above command use the environment variable `$HOME`: `bash -c "cd $HOME/; ..."`

If you look at [`man gnome-terminal`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) (and `gnome-terminal --help`) the options `-x` and `-e` are available (and it is not explicitly written they are deprecated) but all examples there are given by the syntax provided above.

---

I would prefer to use the option `-x` that provides more reliable work than `-e`:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "<my command or script>; exec bash"
```

- The option `-x` means `--execute` *- the  remainder of the command line inside the terminal.*
- And our command is `bash -c "<commands>"`. That means we execute a new `bash` shell, which should run some `-c "<commands>"`.
- We have two separated (by semicolon `; == new line`) `<commands>`.
- The first command `<my command or script>` will execute that we want.
- The second command `exec bash` has a meaning - remain open the current `gnome-terminal` window. There are [another possible approaches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3359/with-a-launcher-for-a-terminal-application-how-can-i-keep-the-terminal-open-aft) to do that. In the current case the command `exec` will *replace the current process image with a new process image* - in other words it will 'kill' the current process and will execute a new (`bash`) under the current PID.

---

More examples of usage of this format:

- [Open a new terminal and source scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965828/open-a-new-ternimal-and-source-scripts/967720#967720)
- [Launch gnome-terminal from SSH session to Desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040852/566421)
- [Start Specific Terminal on Startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965681/start-specific-terminal-on-startup/968541#968541)
- [Crontab and C program that should be executed into a terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955582/crontab-and-c-program-that-should-be-executed-into-a-terminal-window/955591#955591)
- [Xdotool does not minimize terminal window when using in Startup Application when pc boots?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962001/xdotool-does-not-minimize-terminal-window-when-using-in-startup-application-when/962068#962068)

Comment: I got it. If I simply type gnome-terminal -x ./main it won't work. Cause "bash" is the parameter I have to pass to run ./main?

Comment: @J.R. Here is a detailed explanation: https://askubuntu.com/a/967720/566421

Comment: @J.R. I think `gnome-terminal -x ./main` shall work, but the terminal is closed too fast. Also using of `/full/path/` is better than `./`, you also could provide and working directory for the new `gnome-terminal` instance `--working-directory='/home/<user>/....`.

Comment: nice. Thnx for the help. Still one small question. Can I set it to something like the console in a programming IDE? Like the console shows "type anything to continue", then if I type enter the console will be closed rather than typing "exit".

Comment: Hi man I solved it myself by setting export PROMPT_COMMAND="exit"

Comment: Excellent answer! Here's how to make it shell agnostic, starting ZSH or another shell if the user has set that as default:

`gnome-terminal -- $SHELL -c "echo 123; exec $SHELL"`

Comment: use `konsole -e ...` in Kubuntu

Comment: Giving "error constucting proxy for org.gnome.Terminal The connection is closed" in rhel 8,2

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that will keep the window open is to use xterm:

```
xterm -hold -e cmd
```

The hold option keeps the window open.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal -e cmd` will open a terminal window and run `cmd` within it.

Comment: Hi. This is also the weird part with me. After I type "gnome-terminal -e ./main", an extra console is opened but I got a error and the program is not executed correctly. If I run it with built in program like "gnome-terminal -e ls", it seems somethings happened, but no extra console will be opened.

Comment: @J.R. the command is executed but the terminal closes after it executes the command

Comment: @lapisdecor ah, ok, so I should add something like "cmd -k" for genome as well?But why gnome-terminal -e ./main not working?

Comment: try gnome-terminal -e "bash -c ls;bash"

Comment: **Update**: `gnome-terminal` says `-e` may become deprecated, and instead use `gnome-terminal -- commandhere`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and you will open a new terminal.

Try `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c command;bash"`