# Trying to run a script in a new terminal tab from a running script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I'm kind of confused, I thought doing something like this would work :

```
#!/bin/bash

wget https://myscript.sh
chmod +x myscript.sh
exec gnome-terminal --tab --active --title="my title" -- myscript.sh
```

But running this returns :

[image: error message in terminal]

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
>
> Failed to execute child process "myscript.sh" (No such file or directory)

Removing `exec` doesn't work I also tried putting the file name in between `$( )` and `" "`, I also tried putting the absolute path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your goal to crash the system with recursive file loading and processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
gnome-terminal --tab --active --title="my title" -- "/tmp/myworkdir/myscript.sh"
```

having an absolute path will allow for the file to be run.

make sure to makes all your file operations happen in this same directory.

Comment: That just means that `myscript.sh` either doesn't have a shebang line or isn't executable or both.

Comment: I just did, and a script with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, and then `echo foo; sleep 100` will run fine with `gnome-terminal --tab --active --title="my title" -- foo.sh`. It actually fails with `bash foo.sh`!

Comment: Tried both, no difference. Are you _sure_ you have a correct shebang line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96387/discussion-between-terdon-and-tatsu).

Comment: IMO it should be `gnome-terminal --tab --active --title="my title" -- bash -c "/path/myscript.sh; exec bash"`, reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/974782/566421