# How can I run detached command with sudo over ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh, screen

I want to run some script through ssh and detach it, so it run even after ssh session is closed. I need to do this with sudo.

I can run some script but I am not able to detach it.
I tried following commands:

```
ssh 10.0.139.120 -t "sudo -b nohup some_script"
```

and

```
ssh 10.0.139.120 -t "sudo nohup some_script &"
```

Neither of above worked. Every time I get communicate "Connection to 10.0.139.171 closed." and no process is running on server.

I have also tried to do it with screen:

```
ssh 10.0.139.120 -t "sudo screen -S script -md some_script"
```

It did not work either, even though command works when I enter it on server locally.
How can I do it then?

Comment: Do you mean the script needs to be run with `sudo`? I’d try: `ssh 10.0.139.120 -t 'sudo sh -c "nohup some_script &"'`

Comment: I have managed to do it with tmux, but I really would like to know why can'I I do it other way.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30400/execute-remote-commands-completely-detaching-from-the-ssh-connection

Comment: Thanks, I saw that already, but I don't know why this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: It would really help if you could [edit] your question and explain how each of these "didn't work". Did the command not run at all? Did it run but was stopped when you disconnected? Something else? Telling us how they failed will let us understand why they failed and possibly answer you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did small survey and found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29142/6543935) on Stack Overflow. At all you must add path to the script or must go inside the directory, where the script is located:

```bsh
ssh remote-host -t "sudo -b sh -c 'nohup /path/some_script > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

```bsh
ssh remote-host -t "sudo -b sh -c 'cd /path; nohup ./some_script > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

Without `sh -c` or `bash -c` the ampersand `&` at the end breaks the command in some way.

---

I couldn't manage to use `disown` for this purpose, but `setsid` works  well:

```bsh
 ssh remote-host -t 'sudo -b setsid /path/some_script'
```

Comment: Any idea why I can't start and detach script on guest system (Ubuntu server) in VirtualBox? In the other direction it works. I can start session on host from guest.

Comment: Hi, @sbagin13, I do not have any experience with VirtualBox. Is it possible to be an issue with the `$PATH` envvar? Try to redirect the output to some file instead of `/dev/null`, maybe this log will provide some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `disown` to avoid the process being killed after you close you `ssh` session.