# Is it possible to disown a background process and then later open it in another terminal window?

Tags: command-line, bash, process, sh, background-process

Say you have a script that takes a while to do something, but then later requires some user input e.g. something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import time
x=0
while(x<10):
    time.sleep(1)
    x+=1
    print(x)
print(input())
```

and you wanted to run this process in the background and then later recall it in another terminal window, perhaps using

```
./script.py > output.txt & disown
```

This process is no longer listed under `jobs`, but you can see it is still running with `pgrep script.py` (because you disowned it). Thus you can't recall this job with `fg` . Is there a way to re-own the process and/or bring it to the foreground in another terminal window? **This would be particularly useful when you are controlling the machine remotely with ssh and are worried about an unstable connection.**

Comment: That’s a problem commonly solved by using a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`, see the linked questions.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the articles provided. Screen/tmux are not solutions to the problem in the OP. I have made my last sentence boldface to illustrate my point. The point is can you start a process, disown it, close the terminal, and access it again in another terminal, e.g. if it crashes or ssh disconnects

Comment: A parent can inherit jobs, so maybe spawn another term, start your process, background it, then when you want, fg it in the parent.

Comment: The tools like as `screen` and `tmux` are designed exactly for such purposes! However, here is one interesting article: [DigitalOcean: How To Use Bash's Job Control to Manage Foreground and Background Processes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes) And another possible duplication: [Keep running a python program even after logging-off the ssh session](https://askubuntu.com/q/921494/566421).

Comment: @T.ZackCrawford If this question is not a duplicate as specified, explain why in comments or in your question and then ask for it to be reopened.  Justification of why it's not a duplicate is needed first.