# How to start a Zookeeper daemon after booting under specific user in Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: command-line, server, bash, startup

I want to start Zookeeper daemon after Ubuntu server 16.04 booting (not after logging) under user named *zookeeper*. So I changed the file `/etc/rc.local` like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 'never'; defrag_file_pathname

su -c '$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start' zookeeper &

exit 0
```

, adding the line `su -c '$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start' zookeeper &` before `exit 0`. But the process is not started after restarting!

What's wrong here?

**details**: The *zookeeper* user is in *sudo* group and has password.

**details**: When I run command `su -c '$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start' zookeeper &` in terminal, it needs password to run.

Comment: I think Ubuntu 16 is a `systemd` system, so, maybe write a service description file instead? Here's an example btw: https://gist.github.com/gambtho/36a2f01e9e7d8c1b0046fb074f1a44ee (I don't think you need all the details though).

Comment: Hi please explain this `'$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start' zookeeper ` line, is `'$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh start'` different from `zookeeper` or is it an argument pass in?

Comment: The command file path is `$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh ` with `start` argument, and the user I want to run this command with is `zookeeper`. I tried without using variable $ZOOKEEPER_HOME but no difference. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I want to run this command before logging in as user `zookeeper`. The post you suggest, running as a user try to run a command without password as another user.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen My question is the same as that question about running Spark with the difference that I want to run a script as a special user.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Could you post an answer to my question with more details, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a .`service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/zoo.service` and add the following lines:

```
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

[Service]    
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/dir/of/interest
User=zookeeper 
ExecStart=/home/zookeeper_home/bin/zkServer.sh
TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now setup the service:

```
sudo systemctl start zoo
sudo systemctl enable zoo
```

Check status:

```
sudo systemctl status zoo
```

Please read for further details creating daemons:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: Hey your answer is ok but it runs my command under the user `root` but I want it to be run by a user named `zookeeper`, I have created a user named `zookeeper` in advance!

Comment: You know at the first line you said `To run an app with a different name that the source script`. I didn't want to run the app in a different name! I just to run it by a specific user at booting(before logging in)

Comment: Thanks, it solved. New problem is when zookeeper runs, it creates a `zookeeper.out` file on the directory the run command has been issued. For example, if I run it in home directory it creates a `zookeeper.out` file on home directory. Now as Zookeeper start command is running before logging in, it tries to create `zookeeper.out` file on path `/` that has no permission and fails! So is it possible to set command location run it `systemd.unit`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70168/discussion-between-soheil-and-george-udosen).