# Run command on startup with Systemd

Tags: systemd, docker

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/919059/533049) answer as a guide to help me writer a startup script for systemd to start my Jenkins container when my machine boots up. However, the script is not working. Here is the script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker container that houses the Jenkins build service.
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Group=docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start jenkins
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop jenkins

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I placed it in `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service`.

When I run `sudo systemctl start jenkins`, nothing happens. No errors or anything printed out, and the container does not start (if I run `docker ps`, there are no containers listed as running).

I can run `/usr/bin/docker start jenkins` from the command line manually and it starts perfectly fine, so the issue seems to be in the way I've written the script, but I can't figure out why it's not working as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/docker start jenkins"`

Comment: Hmm, that worked once. I ran `sudo systemctl stop jenkins` and then tried to start it again and it would no longer start. Not sure why...

Comment: I answered a similar question about other linux distribution in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438851/start-script-at-boot-for-kali-linux/560551#560551)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your script in `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service`, put a command inside the *~/.bashrc* so that your script runs automatically everytime you boot in Ubuntu (**this will be the same command which you used to run your script from terminal**). This is a bash file which runs whenever your PC boots up in Ubuntu.
For example if I want /home/Kanishk/Pictures/Delhi.png to run whenever I start Ubuntu, I'll put the command `shotwell /home/Kanishk/Pictures/Delhi.png` at the end of *~/.bashrc* file so that Shotwell will open my picture.
**If you rather want to run your Jetkins package instead of that script, put a command to run that instead of the script.**

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438851/start-script-at-boot-for-kali-linux/560551#560551) for another linux distribution. The solution works with systemd to enable the /etc/rc.local file to run commands at startup.

There are some details in the script of that case that you are not using in here:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
```

Then add the following content to it.

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Try using other options for the script to activate logs and figure out what is going on, like:

```
[Manager]
LogLevel=info
LogTarget=syslog|console
```

There are a [myriad](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd-system.conf.5.html) of other options for the systemd configuration that you may use.

Obviously the solution of including the command in the ~/.bashrc file will only run the command when a single user logs in, not a systemwide solution.