# sudo: update-rc.d: command not found (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: command-line, server

I'm trying to get my glassfish server to run as soon as I start the computer, but I run into the following error:

When I try to execute the "update-rc.d" command, it complains that it does not find the command.

[image]

I´m using Ubuntu Server (version 18.04.1). What do I have to do to make this command work? Will there be a substitute command for this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?  It may be necessary to know that information.

Comment: My version is 18.04.1 @ThomasWard

Comment: See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error in your command - update

```
sudo update-rc.d glassfish defaults 90 10
```

Edit :In then image you provided you issued the command `sudo uptade-rc.d glassfish defaults 90 10` which results in the error you received due to the fact that no such executable exists.

Comment: That does not work with systemd see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Answer (score 0):

See Panther's comment above.. I almost missed it:

> That does not work with systemd see
>   digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/… – Panther

This was helpful:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1147142/795299

But if you came here for a GCP GCE VM see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766912/how-do-i-add-a-startup-script-to-an-existing-vm-from-the-developer-console/30766913