# Best Albert alternative for global search

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation, alternative

I searching for a software similar to KRunner or Alfred on MacOS. which is able to to global search on my system and if needed to extra tasks.
I used to use [Albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/), but it seems not to be maintained any longer. [Ulauncher](https://ulauncher.io/) did not convince me and I could not get [CerebroApp](https://cerebroapp.com/) to run, and actually would prefer a more lightweight option.

Is there anything else which works as fast as KRunner on KDE and has the same functions for GNOME?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Albert is still maintained, a new version was released recently: https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/

Comment: Is not abandoned but [its activity slowed down a lot since 2018](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/graphs/code-frequency)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I saw that as well. Let's hope developments speeds up some time again.

Comment: Actually the development has never slowed down. 0.18 was just such a huge change that I could not release. I were just working locally only.

Answer (score 2):

## ulauncher

The best alternative in my opinion is **ulauncher**.

It's discussed to include it as a standard app in Debian and maybe ubuntu will follow.
The [ulauncher homepage](https://ulauncher.io/) gives many plenty of extension and also how to build your own extension.
It is highly configurable and works with plasma (baloo, ...) and gnome.

For installing follow the description on [ulauncher download section](https://ulauncher.io/#Download)
, where a deb or PPA installation links are given.

For the ppa use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:agornostal/ulauncher
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ulauncher
```

To run it as a service using `systemctl` you may copy the following script into your service directory:

```
$ sudo editor /lib/systemd/system/ulauncher.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Linux Application Launcher
Documentation=https://ulauncher.io/
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ulauncher --hide-window

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Now you can start or enable ulauncher as service.

Comment: And it have a [huge extension catalog](https://ext.ulauncher.io/?sorting=github_stars)

Comment: Why you don't run it just at login? Maybe [you should place it on `$HOME/.config/systemd/user`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367237/209677) or [if system-wide](https://askubuntu.com/a/919059/349837)

Comment: Yes good point ! Would be better. `/etc/xdg/autostart/` would be another possibily for system wide autostart.

Comment: XDG Autostart is more for graphical applications you want to show when you log in to your desktop session, while what Ulauncher actually needs is to start a background service and ensure that it keeps running and be prepared for launching. So if you can use systemd it's better.