# I'm trying to start a .jar file with linux boot

Tags: boot, services

Is there a command to make it.
I'm trying to run a .jar file with linux boot and make it run all the time.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Comment: Gentle reminder: Ubuntu 16.04 will reach End Of Life soon. Time to think about migrating to a newer release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in `/lib/systemd/system`. Its name must end with `.service`. For example `myfirst.service`.

Find the full absolute path to java using `which java`
In the file put the following.

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that runs the foo.jar

[Service]
ExecStart=/full/path/to/java -jar /full/path/to/.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it to run at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable myfirst
```

Also refer to [this answer for further clarification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd)

Comment: Good catch. Changed