# Simple /etc/rc3.d startup script is not invoked?

Tags: scripts, startup, etc

I'm running `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-73-generic x86_64)` simple install from DigitalOcean and have installed packages, etc.

Notice this startup test script:

```sh
bryan@db:~$ ls -lh /etc/rc3.d/S02test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43 May 11 20:10 /etc/rc3.d/S02test
bryan@db:~$ cat /etc/rc3.d/S02test
#!/bin/sh
echo TESTHAY "$@" > /testhay.txt
bryan@db:~$
```

But when I reboot with `init 6`, it does not execute.

```sh
bryan@db:~$ ls -lh /testhay.txt
ls: cannot access '/testhay.txt': No such file or directory
bryan@db:~$
```

But running the script manually works... so, how can I make it work on reboot too?

Comment: Why would you be using init scripts in `/etc/rcX.d` instead of systemd units?

Comment: `/etc/rc?.d` is two generations behind the times.

Comment: I'm still curious why it's not working, because there's a bunch of `/etc/rc3.d/S01*` symlinks in there. As for the two newer generations, what's the other one besides systemd units? I will [try systemd units](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd).

Comment: Are you using a Docker image? Since Docker containers doesn't have a working init or systemd system.

Comment: Not using Docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```sh
echo -e '[Unit]\nDescription=rcsng\nRequires=zfs.target\n\n[Service]\nType=forking\nExecStart=sh /700s/start-all.sh\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target' > /etc/systemd/system/700s.service
chmod 740 /etc/systemd/system/700s.service
chgrp staff /etc/systemd/system/700s.service
systemctl enable 700s
```